# How to convert numeric character string into numeric in sas?

Tags: sas

i have numeric string as 00000001234 saved as character in a column, i would like to change this data to numeric with no zeros at the begining?

appriciate your help.

Thanks in advance

tshaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use input function with informat

```
val=input('00000001234',best.);
```

Full list of sas informats you can find in here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001239776.htm

When you are using informats you can define the width of readed string. Default width for informat bast is 12 and the maximum width value is 32. So if your input string is longer then 12 characters you can use:

```
val= input(' 00000000000010373371',best32.);
```

Comment: using the above function it is giving me 0

Comment: could you send an example of your code. I've got result val=1234

Comment: few sample data in the table is as below; 00000000000010373371
00000000000008631413
00000000000002849715
00000000000012265874
00000000000005518733
00000000000005963730
00000000000005071279
00000000000012676647
00000000000011841921
00000000000004029427
00000000000003196529, The data type is Charater 30 and i would like it convert it to numeric 8. without leading zeros. hope this helps.

Comment: use val= input(' 00000000000010373371',best32.)

Comment: @Bagin  You should update your answer to mention the difference between `best.` and `best32.` and when each should be used.